# How to make an array at the object's JSON field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There was such a problem. I can pass a JSON format object

```
[
 {
"title": "test",
"address": "55.99752311227003,49.08959250252893"
 },
 {
"title": "test122",
"address": "63.08891623673952,46.243883499999946"
 },
 {
"title": "test1111",
"address": "55.69684742706125,37.59635133512744"
 },
 {
"title": "kgeu",
"address": "55.816852257889856,49.09529045886616"
 }
]
```

But I need to get a JSON object format

```
[ 
 {
"title": "kgeu",
"address": [55.816852257889856,49.09529045886616]
 }
]
```

setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
     'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    )
}
```

serializers.py

```
class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = ['title', 'address']
```

views.py

```
class FactoryListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Factory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FactorySerializer
```

How to do it? 
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do it like this:

```
class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = ['title', 'address']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """split address."""
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['address'] = ret['address'].split(',')
        return ret
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Including an explanation of your solution, including how it solves the OP's problem, will help others to make sense of your solution.  See the following link for community guidelines on how to answer questions effectively- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

What stack will be used on the retrieving side?

Anyway, as you have stored the coordinates as a string how should Django know that you want it to return a list with latitude and longitude?
What you can do is the following:

## Alternative 1:

Use PostgreSQL and a list field. That returns what you want.

## Alternative 2:

Write a method that returns a list and that Django Rest can read.
This would look like this in your models.py Model:

```
@property
def get_coordinates_formatted(self):
    coordinates = self.address.split(sep=",")
    return [coordinates[0], coordinates[1]]
```

then add this to your serializer.py:

```
address = serializers.Field(source='model.get_coordinates_formatted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by importing the following in your `models.py` file:

`from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`

When you create your model field, you can set it up as:

`my_JSON_field = JSONField(default='')`

Then in your serializer, include:

```
class FactorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    my_JSON_field = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = Factory
        fields = ['my_JSON_field']
```

So when you navigate to the browsable api, you will make a RAW DATA Post request set up in the following way:

```
{
 "my_JSON_field": {
        "title": "kgeu",
        "address": [55.816852257889856,49.09529045886616]
    }
}
```